# how to avoid the "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested" exception on this situation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, insert, cursors

when I run the following script, it runs fine:

```
declare @temp table
(
    name varchar(255),
    field varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255),
    filegroup varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
    maxsize varchar(255),
    growth varchar(255),
    usage varchar(255)
);
INSERT @temp
   exec sp_msforeachdb  @command1='use ?; Exec sp_helpfile;'
```

but when I use my own sp_foreachdb procedure, the source code is on this link below:

[A more reliable and more flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

```
declare @temp table
(
    name varchar(255),
    field varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255),
    filegroup varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
    maxsize varchar(255),
    growth varchar(255),
    usage varchar(255)
);
INSERT @temp
   exec sp_foreachdb  @command='use ?; Exec sp_helpfile;'
```

I get an exception (please note I have added exception handling on that procedure)

```
--EXCEPTION WAS CAUGHT--
THE ERROR NUMBER:8164

SEVERITY: 16
STATE: 1

PROCEDURE: sp_foreachdb
LINE NUMBER: 165

ERROR MESSAGE: 
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
------------------------------------ the sql ------------------------------------

SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1=1 AND state_desc = N'ONLINE' AND is_read_only = 0
Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_foreachdb, Line 239
A cursor with the name 'c' does not exist.
Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_foreachdb, Line 240
A cursor with the name 'c' does not exist.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using this convoluted method. Why not just query sys.master_files?

Comment: @Nic well pointed out, however, I have just used the sp_helpfile as an example. in real life it is one of our own stored procedures that I would be calling

Answer (score 2):

The source code for Aaron's `sp_foreachdb` contains the following line:

`INSERT #x EXEC sp_executesql @sql;`

According to your error message:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

So code like that below will not be valid as it is nesting `INSERT xxx EXEC xxx` code.

```
INSERT @temp
exec sp_msforeachdb  @command1='use ?; Exec sp_helpfile;'
```

Comment: @marcellomiorelli I think it would require a big change to Aaron's SP to remove the dynamic SQL. This would probably require the use of an additional function.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to your own server through distributed query methods would do the trick if sp_foreachdb would return single resultset.

```
create table #temp 
(
    name varchar(255),
    field varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255),
    filegroup varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
    maxsize varchar(255),
    growth varchar(255),
    usage varchar(255)
);

insert into #temp
select  *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'SERVER=****;UID=****;PWD=****',
' exec sp_foreachdb  @command=''  Exec ?..sp_helpfile;''  WITH RESULT SETS         ((name varchar(255),
field varchar(255),
filename varchar(255),
filegroup varchar(255),
size varchar(255),
maxsize varchar(255),
growth varchar(255),
usage varchar(255))); ')

select * from #temp
```

above query will return only the first resultset of sp_foreachdb execution. 
but below query will return the result for all databases in a single resultset.

```
create table #temp 
(
    name varchar(255),
    field varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255),
    filegroup varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
    maxsize varchar(255),
    growth varchar(255),
    usage varchar(255)
);

exec sp_foreachdb  @command='INSERT INTO #temp  Exec ?..sp_helpfile;'
select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adapting Aaron's SP by getting rid of its dynamic part. The dynamic part is supposed to build a query reading just the database names from `sys.databases` based on the arguments supplied. The dynamic SQL is chosen to make the query most efficient – as well as maintainable. Taking into account your specific needs, some sacrifices might be in order.

I would argue, though, that the performance might not suffer much from the rewriting I am offering below, as the `sys.databases` system view usually does not have very many rows, but in any event you could add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the end. However slow it may be, though, it is likely to end up rather ugly, that I can promise.

The method of rewriting is as follows. Aaron's procedure is building the query using a repeating pattern where a parameter value is checked and, based on the result, an additional query is added to the dynamic query, i.e. like this:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1=1'
+ CASE WHEN some_condition1 THEN 'AND some_filter1' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN some_condition2 THEN 'AND some_filter2' ELSE '' END
+ ...
```

Here is how you would rewrite that:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1=1
AND (some_filter1 OR opposite_of_some_condition1)
AND (some_filter2 OR opposite_of_some_condition2)
AND ...
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

For instance, the `@system_only` controls whether the `database_id IN (1,2,3,4)` filter should be included, like this:

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1=1'
    + CASE WHEN @system_only = 1 THEN
        ' AND database_id IN (1,2,3,4)'
        ELSE '' END
```

The rewritten query would be parametrised in this way:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE 1=1
  AND (database_id IN (1,2,3,4) OR @system_only <> 1)  -- or: @system_only = 0
```

Use the resulting query in the cursor directly, instead of

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN @suppress_quotename = 1 THEN
            db
        ELSE
            QUOTENAME(db)
        END
   FROM #x ORDER BY db
```

As can be seen, the final touch would need to go to the SELECT part, where the simple `SELECT name` of the new query would be replaced with

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN @suppress_quotename = 1 THEN name ELSE QUOTENAME(name) END
```

Obviously, you could now also get rid of the `#x` table as no longer needed in the SP.

One last note concerns the specific script you are planning to run against each database. Instead of

```
@command1='use ?; Exec sp_helpfile;'
```

you could have just

```
@command1='Exec ?..sp_helpfile;'
```